# Executing std::system() in class method throws Heap error in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I tried to execute

> std::system(char* string)

from my class method, but I am getting this error regarding heap corruption. My source code looks like this (Codec.cpp):

```
bool Codec::encode(char* fileIn, char* fileOut, int packetSize) {

    // some irrelevant code here

    std:system("pause");  // <-- error: corruption of the heap!
    return true;
}
```

I also tried to execute

> std::system("pause")

directly from my main file (main.cpp), but here debugger passes the line without any error and it works as it should be. I work on WIN32 platform, VS 2010.

Why do I get this HEAP CORRUPTION error?

Comment: The irrelevant bit might be relevant.

Comment: Yeah - what happens if you comment out the irrelevant code?

Comment: Just because this is where the problem is detected doesn't mean that's where it's going wrong. Most likely your code is broken somewhere else - but `std::system` uses something that "discovers" the broken bits (e.g. tries to allocate from a heap that has been corrupted, for example)

Comment: Take a moment and think about how likely it is that `std::system()` is broken vs. how likely it is that something in your program is broken...

Comment: Thank you both for those helpful answers. Yes, my mistake, all code is not "irrelevant". If have figured out that 1 line is making my trouble, i.e. 

"std::sprintf(command, "%s %s lilo %s %s %i\n", programEncoder_, law711_, fileIn, fileOut, packetSize_);"

where "char* command" was incorrectly defined, and so throwing my heap exception. Btw, why is execution of "std::sprintf" impact execution of "std::system" (is there any shared buffer between those two)? How can I clear or reset this buffer? Is there any system integrated "safe" function for executing external shell/cmd console programs?

Comment: `std::system` is perfectly fine, it's just that if you corrupt your environment at any point, every subsequent command becomes a potential point of failure. Instead of looking for a replacement of `std::system`, replace your `char *`s by `std::strings` and your `sprintf`s by `cout`s first.

Comment: Like I said, std::system probably allocates some small block of memory, which causes the "check that heap is healthy" to say "This isn't right".